# ivyPaths in globalSettings for a plugin

Tags: sbt

```
object BlaBlaPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  object autoImport {
    lazy val blabla = settingKey[Unit]("")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override lazy val globalSettings = Seq(
    blabla := println(ivyPaths.value.ivyHome.get.getPath)
  )
}
```

I get:

```
[error] Reference to undefined setting:
[error]
[error] */*:ivyPaths from */*:blabla ((BlaBlaPlugin) BlaBlaPlugin.scala:11)
```

Isn't ivyPaths defined at a Global scope?
I can access it in .sbt/global.sbt but not in the globalSettings of a plugin.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the plugin.

#### projectSettings

> Isn't ivyPaths defined at a Global scope?

No it's not.

```
> inspect ivyPaths
[info] Setting: sbt.IvyPaths = sbt.IvyPaths@13e5338f
[info] Description:
[info]  Configures paths used by Ivy for dependency management.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/xxx/foo/}root/*:ivyPaths
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbt.Classpaths) Defaults.scala:1128
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  *:appConfiguration
[info]  *:baseDirectory
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  *:cleanCacheIvyDirectory
[info]  *:ivyConfiguration
[info]  *:blabla
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:ivyPaths
[info]  {.}/*:ivyPaths
[info]  */*:ivyPaths
```

This shows that `ivyPaths` is in the format of `{file:/Users/xxx/foo/}root/*:ivyPaths`, which is scoped to the current project `root`. If you're in the mood for Star Wars coding (*use the source, Luke*) [Defaults.scala](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.9/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Defaults.scala#L1128) is usually a good place to start.

So the first thing to change would be to use `projectSettings`.

#### override requires

Also note that sbt's builtin settings and tasks are loaded using auto plugins, so if you're depending on them, you need to make sure your plugins are placed after them. To do that you need to override `requires` method as follows:

```
override def requires: Plugins = sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin
```

#### putting it all together

```scala
import sbt._
import Keys._

object BlaBlaPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires: Plugins = sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin
  object autoImport {
    lazy val blabla = settingKey[Unit]("")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    blabla := println(ivyPaths.value.ivyHome.get.getPath)
  )
}
```